# Mongoid behavior when discriminator key is not found

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Looking at [mongoid inheritance documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/7.3/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#inheritance) it says:

> Similarly, when querying by parent classes (Canvas in this example), any documents in the collection that do not have a discriminator value, or whose discriminator value does not map to either the parent or any of its descendants, will be returned as instances of the parent class.

Using the example classes on that page:

```
class Canvas
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :shapes
end

class Browser < Canvas
  field :version, type: Integer
  scope :recent, ->{ where(:version.gt => 3) }
end
```

If I insert a document into the Canvas collection like so:

```
{ 
  "_id": { "$oid": "612d5bd10170cb02ad9bfbac" }, 
  "_type":"SpecialCanvas" 
}
```

And then query for that document like so:

```
Canvas.find_by(id: '612d5bd10170cb02ad9bfbac')
```

I get this error:

```
Mongoid::Errors::UnknownModel:
message:
  Attempted to instantiate an object of the unknown Model 'SpecialCanvas'.
summary:
  A document with the value 'SpecialCanvas' at the key '_type' was used to instantiate a model object but Mongoid cannot find this Class.
resolution:
  The _type field is a reserved one used by Mongoid to determine the class for instantiating an object. Please don't save data in this field or ensure that any values in this field correspond to valid Models.
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mongoid-7.2.5/lib/mongoid/factory.rb:87:in `rescue in from_db'
Caused by NameError: uninitialized constant SpecialCanvas
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
```

But, based on the documentation, I would expect it to just return an instance of the parent class (Canvas). Am I misunderstanding this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a documentation bug to me. Please report it to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID.